# Comparing 4 packages designs preferences based on consumer surveys - statistical significance

Tags: statistical-significance, survey

I'm trying to decide which statistical test to use for the results of 4 surveys we have done. 
We are testing 4 different packaging designs and consumers have answered if they would be willing to buy it or not. We would like to choose the winner, given that the difference in proportions is significantly different.

My data is as simple as this (% just as example, but they are always between 0-100%)
Product A (current design) = 25%
Product B = 27%
Product c = 26.5%
Product D = 28%
Amount of surveys = 410 for each product (individual samples)
We use a survey tool therefore I have no individual answers, just the results.

If there were 2 designs I would simply perform a z-test as it's like an A/B testing. But z-test doesn't work for more than 2 proportions. Or if my intention would be to compare each design vs the current, I could still use this approach. However I want to compare all designs together.
I cannot use ANOVA as they are proportions and they don't have infinite values.

So what should I use? I have googled a lot and couldn't find exactly what I'm looking for.
Thanks a lot! 
Luciana

Comment: Actually, you can use ANOVA. But as you said, the values don't entertain a finite range. The main thing you should check is that the residuals from the ANOVA look approx normal. However, if you want to leverage the fact that your data are proportions, you could investigate the Dirichlet distribution, which is a multivariate Beta distribution

Comment: thanks @jcken I'm now inclined to use a Chi-Square Calculator for Goodness of Fit. I found this example to be quite clear and very related to my issue. https://davidmlane.com/hyperstat/viswanathan/chi_square_marketing.html However I'm not trying to figure out what happens when I have different sample sizes as we performed independent surveys for each product (monadic approach)